# docker sonarqube does fails to load on localhost:9000

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I am trying to run sonarqube locally with Docker. Here are the steps I followed.

- docker pull sonarqube
- docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p
  9092:9092 sonarqube:latest

But I am unable to load sonarqube on localhost:9000. 
Here are the logs from docker container. Can someone please help?

```
2018.08.26 03:14:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2018.08.26 03:14:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2018.08.26 03:14:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.LogServerId] Server ID: AWV0FqFcRJaJHGjIb_AH
2018.08.26 03:14:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.t.TelemetryDaemon] Sharing of SonarQube statistics is enabled.
2018.08.26 03:14:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2018.08.26 03:14:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.GeneratePluginIndex] Generate scanner plugin index
2018.08.26 03:14:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterPlugins] Register plugins
2018.08.26 03:14:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2018.08.26 03:14:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2018.08.26 03:14:55 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.BuiltInQProfileRepositoryImpl] Load quality profiles
2018.08.26 03:14:55 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2018.08.26 03:14:55 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile cs/Sonar way
2018.08.26 03:14:56 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile java/Sonar way
2018.08.26 03:14:56 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile xml/Sonar way
2018.08.26 03:14:56 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile flex/Sonar way
2018.08.26 03:14:56 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile js/Sonar way Recommended
2018.08.26 03:14:56 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile js/Sonar way
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile php/Sonar way
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile php/PSR-2
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile php/Drupal
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile py/Sonar way
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile ts/Sonar way
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Update profile ts/Sonar way recommended
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter@13c8701b [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/measures/component/*, ...], exclusions=[/api/properties*, ...]}]
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.ws.DeprecatedPropertiesWsFilter@6d4b07e1 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/properties/*], exclusions=[]}]
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceReroutingFilter@16e0bddb [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/components/bulk_update_key, ...], exclusions=[]}]
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.InitFilter@3eb3c3b1 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/sessions/init/*], exclusions=[]}]
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter@275b477e [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/oauth2/callback/*], exclusions=[]}]
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction@2afead54 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/authentication/login], exclusions=[]}]
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LogoutAction@5272041d [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/authentication/logout], exclusions=[]}]
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.ValidateAction@58efa7b [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/authentication/validate], exclusions=[]}]
2018.08.26 03:14:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] WebServer is operational
2018.08.26 03:14:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is up
2018.08.26 03:14:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='ce', ipcIndex=3, logFilenamePrefix=ce]] from [/opt/sonarqube]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:./lib/ce/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process4444404552503534548properties
2018.08.26 03:14:58 INFO  ce[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
2018.08.26 03:14:58 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine starting up...
2018.08.26 03:14:59 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.08.26 03:14:59 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.ReindexPlugin]
2018.08.26 03:14:59 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.join.ParentJoinPlugin]
2018.08.26 03:14:59 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]
2018.08.26 03:14:59 INFO  ce[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.08.26 03:15:01 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2018.08.26 03:15:01 INFO  ce[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar
2018.08.26 03:15:01 WARN  ce[][o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Load plugins
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Loaded plugin SonarPython [python]
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Loaded plugin SonarC# [csharp]
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Loaded plugin SonarJava [java]
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Loaded plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: Git [scmgit]
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Loaded plugin Flex [flex]
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Loaded plugin SonarXML [xml]
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Loaded plugin SonarPHP [php]
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Loaded plugin SonarTS [typescript]
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Loaded plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: SVN [scmsvn]
2018.08.26 03:15:03 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Loaded plugin SonarJS [javascript]
2018.08.26 03:15:04 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.q.PurgeCeActivities] Delete the Compute Engine tasks created before Tue Feb 27 03:15:04 UTC 2018
2018.08.26 03:15:05 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine is operational
2018.08.26 03:15:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up
2018.08.26 03:15:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the problem, my docker was using a different IP.

Comment: So what is your actual solution? I am getting a similar problem with starting `sonarqube:community` docker, web SQ does not start on port `9000`.